# Different Loggers with Different configurations Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class LoggingInJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("mylog4j1.properties");
        myLogger.info("1");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("mylog4j2.properties");
        myLogger2.info("2");

        myLogger.info("3");
    }
}
```

I am beginner in logging.

I have two different properties files  - `mylog4j1.properties` has fileappender which outputs to file1  and `mylog4j2.properties` has fileAppender which outputs to file2 .

I want myLogger1 to work with mylog4j1 configurations and similar for next .

But if I write my code as above , I am not getting expected result .

Expected Result:

> file1: 1  3
>   file2: 2

Actual  Result:

> file1: 1
>   file2: 2 3

I did try learning from other questions from stackoverflow but even then I couldnt figure it out .

Please help me find my mistake or whether I am making conceptual error in Log4j framework.

Answer (score 0):

the below code is working fine and it is taking log4j from two different properties files "mylog4j1.properties" and "mylog4j2.properties" and the output is generated to two output files "file1.log" and "file2.log" with the desired output.

```
    import org.apache.log4j.*;

    public class LoggingInJava {

        static final Logger myLogger1 = Logger.getLogger("mylog4j1");
        static final Logger myLogger2 = Logger.getLogger("mylog4j2");

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("mylog4j1.properties");
            myLogger1.info("1");
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("mylog4j2.properties");
            myLogger2.info("2");

            myLogger1.info("3");
        }
    }

mylog4j1.properties
--------------------
log4j.rootLogger=OFF

log4j.appender.myLogger1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.myLogger1.File=logs/file1.log
log4j.appender.myLogger1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLogger1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.mylog4j1=TRACE, myLogger1
log4j.additivity.mylog4j1=false


mylog4j2.properties
--------------------
log4j.rootLogger=OFF

log4j.appender.myLogger2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.myLogger2.File=logs/file2.log
log4j.appender.myLogger2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLogger2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n

log4j.category.mylog4j2=TRACE, myLogger2
log4j.additivity.mylog4j2=false
```

Comment: Thank You , I think I got a better understanding of configuration of log4j . I just have one more doubt : Is PropertyConfigurator() needed because you defined loggers in properties in itself?

Answer (score 0):

Why you use two `properties` files? You can do this from 1 properties file.

Here is the sample for, how implement that

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/logs/firstLog.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n

log4j.appender.SECOND=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SECOND.File=/home/logs/secondLog.log
log4j.appender.SECOND.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.SECOND.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.SECOND.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SECOND.Append=true
log4j.appender.SECOND.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, FILE

log4j.category.testngLogger=DEBUG, SECOND
log4j.additivity.testngLogger=false
```

Comment: Do you know how the appenders get parameters from properties file?

Comment: I just do not understand how log4j works from inside with properties . Like how it configures output to filename from .File property , I can see setFile() method but how setFile() is getting its argument ??

Comment: Do you want to get values from Properties file? 
or
Do you want to make log files? above properties file makes that, when you set your own details to separate files, it will log in mentioned path. Ex : `fileLogger.info("This is FILE related")` and `secondLogger.info("This is SECOND related")`

Comment: Suppose , I want to change properties in runtime . Example , like if the class logs into file1.log , I want to change it to file2.log under certain if else or other  condition then later to some other file3.log  . That was an example of my doubt . My whole point is I want to know how log4j works i.e. how it takes values from properties files .